# `this` in global scope in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-harmony

I've tried looking in the ES6 draft myself, but I'm not sure where to look:

Can someone tell me if `this` in ES6 necessarily refers to the global object? Also, will this object have same members as the global scope?

If you could answer for ES5 that would be helpful as well.

I know `this` in global scope refers to the global object in the browser and in most other ES environments, like Node. I just want to know if that's the defined behavior by the spec or if that's extended behavior that implementers have added (and if this behavior will continue in ES6 implementations). In addition, is the global object always the same thing as the global scope? Or are there distinctions?

---

**Update - Why I want to know:** I am basically trying to figure out how to get the global object reliably in ES5 & 6. I can't rely on `window` because that's specific to the browser, nor can I rely on `global` because that's specific to environments like Node. I know `this` in Node can refer to `module` in module scope, but I think it still refers to `global` in global scope. I want a cross-environment ES5 & 6 compliant way to get the global object (if possible). It seems like in all the environments I know of `this` in global scope does that, but I want to know if it's part of the actual spec (and so reliable across any environment that I may not be familiar with).

I also need to know if the global scope and the global object are the same thing by the spec. In other words will all variables in global scope be the same as `globalobject.variable_name`?

---

**Update 2 - What I'm trying to do:**

I have developed some [ES6 shims for ES5 environments](https://github.com/Nathan-Wall/inHarmony). I want to know the best way to (1) check to see if the ES6 built-ins already exist so that they can be used when possible instead of my shims, and (2) add my shims to the global scope if the built-ins do not already exist.

Currently I'm following this pattern:

```
(function() {

    // Indirect eval to run in global scope.
    // (We get whatever "this" is in global scope, hoping that it's the global object...
    // Whether this line does what I want it to is the crux of my question.)
    var global = (0, eval)('this');

    // If Symbol does not already exist in global scope,
    if (!global.Symbol)

        // Then add Symbol to global scope.
        global.Symbol = (function() {

            // ...
            // Return my Symbol shim

        })();

})();
```

There are some other possibilities for (1), but at the end of the day I need a way to add something to global scope without using `var` in global scope (because that would override the built-ins before I can check for them, due to `var` hoisting [at least in the naive case, perhaps I could indirect `eval` a `var` statement as well?]). I want my code to be able to run in strict mode, so that compounds the problem.

I have discovered that, by the ES5 spec, indirect `eval` executes code in global scope. So I am at least able to do that. My questions are if I get `this` in global scope, (1) Will checking the properties of that object let me know if a built-in already exists in global scope? and (2) Will adding properties to that object allow me to add variables to global scope?

Comment: It should work like previous ES specs as `this` is not ES6 specific. The meaning of `this` depends on where it is used, and is not always the global object.

Comment: Understood; that's why I asked "in global scope", where in browsers `this` is the same as `window` which is also the global object. I do not know, however, if this is specified in ES or if it's just a browser extension to the language.

Comment: As long as you're not in something like SES, the indirect eval trick will work reliably. Once you have the global object you can assign to it and check properties and this will do what you want. In es6, beyond what Andreas said about let, const, etc. there's also the matter of modules having their own private global that has the main global object as an outer scope, so it's impossible to access or modify the outer global unless a direct reference to it is provided (like node.js defining 'global' automatically, for example, would give you a reference to that outer global).

Comment: Thanks benvie! The information about modules is helpful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `this` in global scope will continue to refer to the global object in ES6. (Generally, ES6 is supposed to be fully backwards compatible, i.e. any code that was guaranteed to work in ES5 should also work in ES6).

The notion of "global scope", however, will no longer be identical with the global object in ES6. It introduces new declaration forms that are lexically scoped (`let`, `const`, `class`, `module`, and a few more). The conclusion at the last meeting was that none of these will appear as properties of the global object. There is a variety of technical and methodological reasons for that, but the bottom line is that it is best to avoid using the global object directly altogether (this has always been true, but is even more so in ES6).

Is there something specific you need the global object for?

Comment: Hey Andreas, thanks for offering your expertise! I have answered your question about why I want the global object in **Update 2** of my original post. Could you take a look and see if the pattern I am following is a good one? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mostly yes.

Passing `this` in any non-object (or non-set `this`) will refer to the global object:

```
(function( global ){ /* do stuff! */ }(this));
```

This behavior is intended to stay in ES6 (for understandable backward compatibility issues). And that's how most of multiplatform (Browser/Node) plugins I know of are accessing the global object. For example: https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L12

Although, it's true that plugin on the server only access `this` as being `module` (which is exported). But, that's what you want in node. Your global space isn't cleaned up ever (except if done manually, or on server restart). So it's shared between all client connections; assigning anything to the global space is really not a good idea.

---

The only notable difference in how `this` is handled between javascript "version" is in `strict mode`, where it will throw an error is if `null` or `undefined` is passed to `call` or `apply` or `bind` (in the position of the `this value`). In un-strict mode, `this` was only coerced to the global object.

```
"use strict";
foo.apply(null); // Throw error
```

Hope this help!

Comment: You may have just been unclear in your phrasing, but `foo.apply(null);` does not throw an error in strict mode. `function foo() { this.doSomething(); }` throws an error in strict mode if there is no `this` (eg if `this` is `null` or `undefined`). That may be what you meant to say, but you may want to write it more clearly for posterity.