# this in a strict mode in a global scope (in ES2015)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Could someone please point to the place in the ES2015 standard that states what the `this` must refer to when used in a strict mode in a global scope?

I have found that it is equal to the `window` in my firefox and chrome, but is not equal to `window` in my IE11 under windows 7 x64.

The only relevant place in the standard I could find is [ES2015 - The Strict Mode of ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-of-ecmascript) but it looks vague and does not state that explicitly.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments on another question, IE11 (11.0.10240.16384) on Windows 10 x64 does not appear to exhibit this behavior, so there may be something else going on here as well. The question on what the spec defines is definitely interesting though.

Comment: Related question: [`this` in global scope in ECMAScript 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425333/this-in-global-scope-in-ecmascript-6).

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question (it's rather implicit), but the [spec says about `HasThisBinding` says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-environment-records-hasthisbinding): *"Global Environment Records always provide a this binding whose value is the associated global object."*. You can see in other cases (e.g. Function Environment Records) that the logic is more complex (even though it doesn't explicitly mention strict mode).

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript spec does not define which object should be the global in particular runtime environments. For browsers this is defined by the [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#global-object). There is some special-casing for `window` via the [windowproxy](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#windowproxy) object, but that should generally be invisible to javascript.

I.e. even if top level `this !== window` in a browser script this does not necessarily stem from ecma spec properties or strict mode. It could also stem from from the html spec's definition what a global ought to be for that particular script environment or whether that global actually equals `<local variable bindings>.window`.

---

An issue with your question is what you call the *global scope*. The spec has a concept of [global lexical environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-lexical-environments). But not all script bodies (source code) are evaluated with a realm's global lexical environment as their lexical environment.

A further complication is that that scripts can not just run in different lexical environments but that there can also be multiple *realms* which can interact and yet have distict globals.

This may seem like a non-issue because different code realms (e.g. workers or browser windows) mostly interact through small API surfaces, but reality is more complex than that. E.g. one realm can use a global object which has a prototype which is a proxy to a different realm's global. In many ways they will look like sharing a global when they actually are not and doing something like `this == this.referenceToSelf` may return false. This commonly happens with firefox's [sandboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox) which are used to run addons/webextensions/userscripts.

---

A counterexample where a "top level" `this` is not the global object would be es6 modules.

- [looking up `this`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-resolvethisbinding) is done iteratively [by traversing lexical environment chain upwards](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getthisenvironment), checking its abstract `HasThisBinding()` property
- Modules have a [this binding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-module-environment-records-hasthisbinding)
- that binding [returns `undefined`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-module-environment-records-getthisbinding)
- modules [run in strict mode](http://strict%20mode%20code)

So there exists strict mode code where `this` in the top level lexical is not the global object.

A much more trivial example is code eval'd in the context of a function. It inherits the `this` from the function.

Comment: The question is if it should even refer to a global object or not. It's not about what `window` should be. Sorry, but not an answer.

Comment: You still cannot apply the ecma spec in a vacuum. What the lexical environment of a particular script is - and thus its `this` binding - depends on choices made by the runtime, in other words, how html specifies that `<script>` tags should be executed. If you want to formally derive what `this` is in a particular scope then you have to take both specs into account.

Comment: "you have to take both specs into account" --- I'm not sure how the `this` value can be of HTML standard business. Does it even know anything about it? If so - which standard restricts on the value for `this` in a strict mode?

Comment: The issue is that you're asking whether top level this == global. But your question is motivated by top level this == window, in a <script> tag in a browser. There is a gap between those two. First of all you need to establish that window == global (html spec). Then you figure out how script tags are evaluated, they could do crazy things like creating new realm or evaluate in function environments (html spec). Only then you can determine what actually happens at the top level scope or whether strict mode makes any difference (es2015 spec).

Comment: "But your question is motivated by top level this == window, in a <script> tag in a browser. There is a gap between those two" --- there is no. If you read the question once again you would see that **THE ONLY QUESTION I ASKED** states nothing about `window`: "what the this must refer to when used in a strict mode in a global scope". "Then you figure out how script tags are evaluated" --- the question is not about browsers specifically, those were used just because I could demonstrate the difference in behaviour easily. It could be nodejs or iojs or any other implementation.

Comment: Well, if I read the spec correctly then in other environments `this` may be `undefined`. Specifically module environments are defined to have a *this binding* and that this binding is `undefined`. Modules also evaluate in strict mode, therefore some strict mode code may have top level this != global object.

Comment: If that (with quotes/references to the spec) is put as an answer that would count :-)